# Effect of Change in Mass on Planetary Motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, orbital-motion, planets, solar-system

How would a change in the mass of a planet in the solar system affect its orbit? For example, if hypothetically the mass of Mars were doubled, would it [a] move closer to the Sun, [b] move further from the Sun, or [c] remain in the same orbit; presuming that in the case [c], the orbital period must remain unchanged?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: On the contrary, the sun is losing mass due to nuclear fusion.

Answer (score 2):

It would not change.

The reason is that the mass of the planet can be simplified out of the orbital equation. Consider a planet of mass $m$ moving around the sun of mass $M$ at a distance $r$ and velocity $v$. Then the gravitational force on the planet is $F_{grav}=-\frac{GMm}{r^2}$, and to this we can add the centrifugal force $F_{grav}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ to get $$F_{total}=\left (-\frac{GM}{r^2}+\frac{v^2}{r}\right ) m.$$ But Newton's law gives $F=ma$, so the acceleration, which determines how the velocity and hence the position changes, will be independent of $m$: $a=-\frac{GM}{r^2}+\frac{v^2}{r}.$

Now, this is the standard answer. In reality what happens depends on *how* the mass of the planet changes. When adding or removing chunks of planet they will have their own momentum, and this will change $v$. If the change happens because of an imaginary mass-change device we might ask whether it conserves kinetic energy (in which case the velocity would be increased to counter the lower mass, $v_{new}=v_{old}\sqrt{m_{old}/m_{new}}$ ) or momentum (in which case the velocity increases in a different way to counter the lower mass, $v_{new}=v_{old}(m_{old}/m_{new})$). If you do change the velocity, then the orbit will change, so the standard answer to your question is only true for the case where momentum and kinetic energy are not conserved.

The same thing is true in general relativity because of the [equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle), which states that the orbit is only determined by the shortest path through the curved spacetime set up by the sun. Were the planet heavy enough it would add some curvature to complicate the situation, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the rest of the solar system the problem reduces to the gravitational two-body problem. The equation of motion is $\vec{\ddot{r}} = -\frac{G(m_m+m_s)}{r^2} \hat{r} $, where $r=r_m-r_s$.
In the limit that $m_m << m_S$, obviously, a change of $m_m$ makes no difference.

For finite $m_m$ such a change *does* affect the motion, as the force in the equation of motion increases. The requirement that $v_m$ remains the same implies, in my expectation, that also the orbital eccentricity changes.

If the other planets are taken into account  the impact of a mass change is even more involved.

Note: the previous answer given on this site implicitly assumes heliocentric coordinates, in which the sun does not move. Because the sun actually *is* moving this is equivalent to the approximation that $m_m<<m_s$.